# Action not getting dispatched on page load in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am calling my action 'GetMobileList' on page load. but after the action is executed nothing gets called like mapstatestoprops or any reducer. They get called before action is called and after the action is called nothing happens. I am binding a list on page load.After the action is completed I am rendering the list component via props of the parent component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GetProductsList from './list'
import GetMobileList from '../actions/index'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class Add extends Component
{
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount()
    {
        GetMobileList();
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <GetProductsList mobilesList={this.props.mobiles}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        mobiles: state.mobiles
    }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps,{GetMobileList}) (Add)
......................................................
    
export default  function GetMobileList()
{
    var mobiles= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mobiles'));
    return  {
        type:'MOBILE_LIST',
        payload :  mobiles
    };
}

Index.js for Reducer

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import MobilesList from './mobileslist';

const rootreducer = combineReducers({
    mobiles:MobilesList
});

export default rootreducer;

REDUCER -

export default function (state=null,action)
{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'MOBILE_LIST':
        {
            return action.payload
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `matchDispatchToProps`, `GetMobileList` becomes a prop.

So instead of calling as `GetMobileList()`, try `this.props.GetMobileList()`

Comment: You should say in `mapDispatchToProps` instead of `mapStateToProps`